# Read a base 64 encoded image from memory using OpenCv python library

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, encoding, base64

I'm working on an app that to do some facial recognition from a webcam stream. I get base64 encoded data uri's of the canvas and want to use it to do something like this:

```
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

The data URI looks something like this:

```
 data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7
```

So, for clarity I've shown what the image looks like so the base64 string is not broken.

```html
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7">
```

The [official doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html) says, that `imread` accepts a file path as the argument. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16214280/1083314) SO answer, if I do something like:

```
 import base64
 imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring) #I use imgdata as this variable itself in references below
 filename = 'some_image.jpg'
 with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
```

The above code snippet works and the image file gets generated properly. However I don't think so many File IO operations are feasible considering I'd be doing this for every frame of the stream. I want to be able to read the image into the memory directly creating the `img` object.

I have tried two solutions that seem to be working for some people.

1. Using PIL [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11601466/1083314):

   ```
   pilImage = Image.open(StringIO(imgdata))
   npImage = np.array(pilImage)
   matImage = cv.fromarray(npImage)
   ```

   I get `cv` not defined as I have openCV3 installed which is available to me as `cv2` module. I tried `img = cv2.imdecode(npImage,0)`, this returns nothing.
2. Getting the bytes from decoded string and converting it into an numpy array of sorts

   ```
   file_bytes = numpy.asarray(bytearray(imgdata), dtype=numpy.uint8)
   img = cv2.imdecode(file_bytes, 0) #Here as well I get returned nothing
   ```

The documentation doesn't really mention what the `imdecode` function returns. However, from the errors that I encountered, I guess it is expecting a `numpy array` or a `scalar` as the first argument. How do I get a handle on that image in memory so that I can do `cv2.imshow('image',img)` and all kinds of cool stuff thereafter.

I hope I was able to make myself clear.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33522724/5008845)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Miki, but `np.fromstring` doesn't work as well.

Comment: And `imgstring` would be image URL, right?

Comment: @Divakar, it is the base64 encoded string representing that image

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use both cv2 and pillow like this:

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
import cv2
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np

def readb64(base64_string):
    sbuf = StringIO()
    sbuf.write(base64.b64decode(base64_string))
    pimg = Image.open(sbuf)
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pimg), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cvimg = readb64('R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7')
cv2.imshow(cvimg)
```

Comment: Hi, I am running this piece of code but it is throwing:
 line 9, in readb64
    sbuf.write(base64.b64decode(base64_string))
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

How to fix this?

Comment: @AbhilashRamteke change `base64_string` to `base64_string.encode('ascii')`

Answer (score 41):

This is my solution for python 3.7 and without using PIL

```
import base64

def readb64(uri):
   encoded_data = uri.split(',')[1]
   nparr = np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(encoded_data), np.uint8)
   img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   return img
```

i hope that this solutions works for all

Comment: base64.b64decode returns a byte array, so I got it working with np.frombuffer(...) instead of np.fromstring(...)

Comment: `np.fromstring` is deprecated on byte input, instead use `np.frombuffer`.

Answer (score 34):

(Edit: Updated for python 3)
This worked for me on python 3, and doesn't require PIL/pillow or any other dependencies (except `cv2`):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64

def data_uri_to_cv2_img(uri):
    encoded_data = uri.split(',')[1]
    nparr = np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(encoded_data), np.uint8)
    # old (python 2 version):
    # nparr = np.fromstring(encoded_data.decode('base64'), np.uint8)

    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return img

data_uri = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ..."
img = data_uri_to_cv2_img(data_uri)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You saved my life ! I'm (obliged to) using Python 2 on AWS and the first solution kept giving me an error like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226308/cv2-cvtcolor-error-215-scn-3-scn-4-in-function-cvcvtcolor

Comment: if returning type(img) i get NoneType. Seems the cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) does not work as wanted

Comment: @JoePlatano So what is the solution?

Comment: `np.fromstring` is deprecated on byte input, instead use `np.frombuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple solution.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64
image = ""  # raw data with base64 encoding
decoded_data = base64.b64decode(image)
np_data = np.fromstring(decoded_data,np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(np_data,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow("test", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/HoweChen/7cdd09b08147133d8e1fbe9b52c24768

Comment: This is a duplicate of an existing answer