# Base64 encode file while uploading in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, base64

Have you any idea base64 encode of file in flask?

I have tried ...

```
import base64


@users_blueprint.route('/add-source', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@ensure_authenticated
@user_authenticated

def add_user_resource():
    file = request.files['file']

    #file = request.files['file'].filename

    with open(file, "rb") as imageFile:
        str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
        print str  
    return str
```

I got error
**#FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Tulips.jpg'**

any idea? Thank you in advance?

https://pastebin.com/nGubkfeY

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754935/read-a-base-64-encoded-image-from-memory-using-opencv-python-library) will help

Comment: It is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to call `open`. Flask already provides you with a readable file stream.

Also, note that [`b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) returns `bytes` and not `str`.

```py
file = request.files['file']
rv = base64.b64encode(file.read())  # bytes
rv = rv.decode('ascii')  # str
return rv
```

PS: When choosing variable names, try to avoid [built-in identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html) such as `str`. It can save you some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file with a relative file path (i.e. simply passing `Tulips.jpg`) a path to a file is calculated relatively to the current working directory. If a file is not there — you'll get an error. Easy way to debug in your case is to print current working dir on app startup or right before file opening with [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) and check if file actually at `/your/working/dir/Tulips.jpg`.