# Decode base64 image in JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, base64

I receive from front-end an image in base64 into JSON file, and need take image and decode with OpenCV, the JSON there is:

```
{
     'photo': "b'/9j/4AAQSkZJR...(continue)"
}
```

and code is

```
obj = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
obj = obj['foto']
obj = bytes(obj,'utf-8')

obj_d = base64.decodebytes(obj)
print(type(obj_d))

img_buffer = np.frombuffer(obj_d, dtype=np.uint8)
print(img_buffer)
img = cv2.imdecode(img_buffer, flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
print(img.shape)
```

And received error is, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'.

When I code and decode in base64 the image in the Python, I not have problem.

Comment: people need to use debuggers, it helps a lot. Pycharm / Vscode are free and have great debuggers.

Comment: you might have to `eval()` the string that because it starts with `b'...'` but y'know security

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a base 64 encoded image from memory using OpenCv python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754935/read-a-base-64-encoded-image-from-memory-using-opencv-python-library)

Comment: in the JSON you have 'photo' but in your code you try to read `obj['foto']`. This might be the problem.

Comment: JSON have obj['foto'], I wrote a previous version, and the error is with **b**'...', deleted this and works, thanks for yours help

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON I wrote previous version(not error in here), the error is in **b**'...', I deleted this in front-end or with other method and works